# Can Big(O) be affirmed by measurement?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Let's say you have designed an algorithm which you might think runs in O(n). If I measure the time it runs with 1000 input and then increase the input 10x and then measure again. Can I infer that O(n) is correct iff run time is almost 10 times the first try?

How stupid would this be? Obviously repeating the test would give a better accuracy but I wanna know if this makes sense at all.

Comment: Often, the answer is 'yes'.  If you increase the problem size by 10 and the time goes up by 10, you're probably OK.  However, the number is unlikely to quite so beautiful.  If you go from 1,000 to 10,000, an O(N.logN) algorithm goes up by a factor of 13, roughly.  That's not far off 10.  However, if you increase by 10 and the time goes up by 100, you're likely dealing with a non-linear algorithm - O(N^2) probably.  So, 2 points is not enough, but it is indicative.  Multiple runs and more data points both help.

Comment: Affirm? Yes.  Prove? No.  Disprove?  Sort of.

Comment: Of course it can, wouldn't be useful otherwise.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Often, the answer is 'yes'. If you increase the problem size by 10 and the time goes up by 10, you're probably correct to assume O(N). However, the number is unlikely to quite so beautiful.

If you go from 1,000 to 10,000, an O(N.logN) algorithm goes up by a factor of 13, roughly (see the `bc` below). That's not far off 10, and you might mistakenly think that an increase of 12 indicates O(N.logN) rather than O(N). However, if you increase by 10 and the time goes up by about 100, you're likely dealing with a non-linear algorithm — O(N<sup>2</sup>) probably. So, 2 points is not enough, but it is indicative. Multiple runs and more data points both help.

Sometimes, though, something else kicks in.  For example, you might suddenly start using so much memory that your program is paged instead of just running.  It will slow down dramatically, even though the algorithm is still linear given enough resources.

Also, beware caching effects and optimization effects.  Caching can make things seem faster.  If the optimizer concludes that the calculation is ignored, it might eliminate the entire calculation.  So you have to be cautious.

But, with a bit of luck, you can scale the problem a few orders of magnitude (or, at least, a few different numbers) and come up with a reasonable guess as to whether it is linear or something else.

#### O(N.logN) for 1,000 vs 10,000

```
$ bc -l
n=1000
n*l(n)
6907.75527898213705205000
a=n*l(n)
m=n*10
m*l(m)
92103.40371976182736070000
b=m*l(m)
b/a
13.33333333333333333333
quit
$
```

Comment: To all of this I will add that you never know when there is a tiny higher order term lurking to catch you.  For example many years ago Perl's `map` function was quadratic in a 2 for 1 map.  The quadratic bit was barely visible to 10,000 elements.  But dominated at 100,000.

Comment: @btilly: All sorts of funny things happen as other things grow.  I once encountered a `strstr()` that had a `strlen()` in its controlling loop — on a well-known but now very ancient Unix O/S (I'm discussing circa 1990).  It worked fine with small strings under say 1 KiB; it gave quadratic performance on 20 KiB strings, which was the size I was working with, and made a program that ran very fast on another O/S run very slowly on this one.  The bug was fixed shortly afterwards.

Comment: Also, I note my answer starts with "Often, the answer is 'yes'."  That implies that sometimes the answer is 'no'.  If you test the performance over the range of sizes you're interested in and the algorithm behaves linearly, then it is effectively linear, even if there is a non-linear effect at some size outside the range you're interested in.

Answer (score 6):

On the contrary to the other answer, I will say "no". However, you can get a pretty good guess (not even an estimate as it is not appropriate here). This is probably what is meant by "often".

The thing is, that you never know the constant factors. Big Oh is asymptotic behaviour (in infinity), this is a very very useful to drop everything except for the most growing term. So mathematically you cannot confirm your assumption.

Firstly, here is plenty of algorithms and use-cases when asymptotic behaviour is not useful in real-life applications. Simply because "typical use-case" input distribution falls off. This is more often case. And you could still test/"estimate" it.

But there is also a case where the best algorithm has such big constant factors it is not applicable on modern systems. The best example I know are [large number multiplication algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Fast_multiplication_algorithms_for_large_inputs).

However, there are systems that "approximate" (better said guess) complexity class of an algorithm. I am not sure whether Codility_ measure it or get their guess by code analysis but they are able to do it: https://app.codility.com/public-report-detail/.

What could be done do is to run an algorithm, and change input size, run tests and fit the data to model. It's quite simple. Then you can say that for tested input range the algorithms *behaves as* `O(class(n))`. (This might have a practical meaning valuable even more than theoretical asymptotic complexity.)

Note that choosing the testing points is not trivial. Basically if your algorithm behaves "fast" then you need to increase input size rate to the next class. E.g. if you have something like `(100n+n!)` you can go `n={1,10,100}` because it will `kill` execution time. However going `n={1,2,3,4,5,6,7}` won't pick up the `n!` part (ok `7!` is `5040` but for `n^2` it would be much harder).

Bottom line, getting a nice guess is certainly possible, but beyond most simple cases it can be tricky and hard to do, and sadly it is quite hard to tell if case is tricky or not.

Also, this discussion is purely theoretical, skipping hardware effects. I have heard said of algorithms that `n^2` behaved better than `n^log n` because former was always (very) cache friendly, but don't take my word for it, I can't recall source.

Answer (score 2):

Plotting input size against run-time for actual programs is an extremely helpful tool to let you see how your code actually performs. In general, it's dangerous to think you can use it to infer complexity.

Here's a practical example of one way it breaks down.

Good quick-sort implementations pivot the array into three parts: less than the pivot, equal to the pivot, and greater than the pivot. That means that quick-sorting a random array 64-bit ints (in fact, sorting a random array of any fixed-size datatype) uses O(n) comparisons because eventually every sub-array will be constant.

Unfortunately, you can't see this empirically: if you plot n against the number of comparisons, the graph looks like n*log(n) until the input array gets much larger than 2^64 elements. Even if you had enough memory, your programming language probably doesn't allow you to index arrays of that size.

This also example demonstrates that empirical measurement gives you interesting data (that the code performs like n*log(n) on actual input), and complexity gives you a theoretical but practically useless fact about asymptotic growth being linear.

Comment: Another case where theoretical and empirical analysis will often given different results is when the complexity of the algorithm depends on the number of distinct characters a string can have; the Unicode specification (at the time of writing) defines 144,697 characters, which is a large constant, but a constant nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what others have said. Sometimes the average case and worst case may be different, and the worst case may be hard to find. A famous example is `quicksort`, with its `O(n log n)` average behaviour (abuse of the `O` notation?), and `O(n^2)` worst case behaviour. If you have been given a "black-box" algorithm (well, program), such worst cases may be hard to catch experimentally without the knowledge about the algorithm.

Comment: The quicksort worst cases aren't hard to find for the naïve pivot selection of 'central value in range'.  The worst cases are already sorted or uniform data.  However, you're right that worst-case scenarios might be hard to find.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for catching the ambuiguity in my writing. What I mean by "such cases" is given a black box algorithm (and not `quicksort` in particular), for which you only know what it does and not how, it may not be easy to land up into worst cases experimentally.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Edited accordingly.